# Operating on two shorts at once by combining them into an integer

Tags: c++, optimization, bit-manipulation

I'm using the following code to map two signed 16-bit integers to the upper and lower 16 bits of an unsigned 32 bit integer.

```
inline uint32_t to_score(int16_t mg, int16_t eg) {
    return ((1u * mg) << 16 | (eg & 0xFFFF));
}

inline int16_t extract_mg(uint32_t score) {
    return int16_t(score >> 16);
}

inline int16_t extract_eg(uint32_t score) {
    return int16_t(score & 0xFFFF);
}
```

I need to perform various calculations on both the `mg` and `eg` parts simultaneously, before interpolating the two parts at the end of a function.

As I understand it, as long as there is no overflow, it should be safe to add two `uint32_t`s created `to_score`, and then extract the `int16_t`s to find the results of the individual calculations: i.e. the results if I added the the values for `mg` and `eg` separately.

I'm not sure whether this assumption holds if either `mg` or `eg` are negative, or whether this method can be used for subtraction, multiplication and/or division.

Which operations can I expect to function correctly? Are there alternative ways of representing two integers which can be added/subtracted/multiplied quickly?

Comment: `eg & 0xFFFF`, that's seems odd. It should be of the proper length, but it's signed instead of requiring to be unsigned.

Comment: Can you use uint16_t instead of int16_t?  I'm pretty sure that int16_t does not qualify as "safe" for the way you want to do those operations.  Assuming you care about portability.  You may be interested in a book called Hacker's Delight, by Henry S. Warren Jr., which covers many kinds of interesting bit twiddling techniques.

Comment: By the way these pseudo-parallel calculation style is sometimes called SWAR (SIMD within a register)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a problem with a carry going from the low half into the high half, but it can be avoided with extra operations, as detailed on for example [chessprogramming.org/SIMD_and_SWAR_Techniques](https://www.chessprogramming.org/SIMD_and_SWAR_Techniques)

```
z = ((x &~H) + (y &~H)) ^ ((x ^ y) & H)
```

Where in this case `H = 0x80008000`.

As an other alternative, it could be done with two additions, but with optimized extraction/recombination:

```
// low half addition, leaving upper half corrupted but it will be ignored
l = x + y
// high half addition, adding 0 to the bottom so no carry
h = x + (y & 0xFFFF0000)
// recombine
z = (l & 0xFFFF) | (h & 0xFFFF0000)
```

Subtraction is a minor variation on addition.

Multiplication unfortunately cares about absolute bit-positions, so values have to be moved (shifted) to their notional position for it to work. *Actual* SIMD can still be used though, such as `_mm_mullo_epi16` with SSE2.

Comment: SWAR looks interesting, but I suppose it would end up being slower than computing the values separately. Good to know about that option though.

Comment: This can be done slightly simpler by just subtracting the false overflow: s = x + y; return s - ((x ^ y ^ s) & 0x10000)

Answer (score 1):

C++ signed integers are two's complement, it is on the way to be standardized in C++20, in practice you may already assume that.

Some cases of addition and subtraction would work, those cases that don't cause either of following: eg to overflow, mg to overflow, mg to change sign.

The optimization does not make much sense.

If there's larger array, you can try to get your operations vectorized with proper SIMD instruction, if they are available for your platform by enabling compiler optimization or by using intrinsics ( _mm_adds_pi16 might be the one you need ).

If you have just two integers, just compute them one by one.